# Vectorizing a function (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, scalar

I'm new to python and trying to do a HW assignment and it keeps throwing this error back at me (in iPython Notebook):

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'float'"
```

Here's the formula i'm trying to imitate: h(x)=(1/√2π)*e^−(1/2)^x^2

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import *


def h_scalar(x):
    return (1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-.50** x ** 2.00)
```

I'm trying to get the same out put as my teacher.

```
l = [-10.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0] #
print h_scalar(l)
>>> [1.4867195147342977e-06, 0.24197072451914337, 0.3989422804014327,
0.24197072451914337, 1.4867195147342977e-06]
```

Here's the teachers question btw:

> First of all, write a function called h_scalar. The function should expect a list (or in general an item that is iterable). It will expect that the list contains floating point values. It should return a new list of floats that are the h(x) for each x value in the input list. You should name your function h_scalar()

Comment: 1.) Your exponential should be `-.50 * x ** 2.00`. 2.) You cannot broadcast an operation like `**2.00` across a standard python array. To do this, convert `x` to a `np.array`. 3.) If you don't want to use numpy, consider using a `for` loop to compute the formula for each element in `x`. Store these values in another array, which you then return. Alternatively, use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 8):

You will achieve a better performance using `numpy`'s `sqrt` and `exp`, which will operate elementwise:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, exp, pi
def h_scalar(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    return (1/sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-0.50*x**2)
```

You can use it like:

```
x = [-10.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0]
h_scalar(x)
```

Comment: +1 this is the only solution so far that gains a proper performance advantage from vectorization

Comment: To meet the requirements of the input being a list (or any iterable) you should insert `x=np.array(x, copy=False)` as the first line of the function `h_scalar`.

Comment: @Dave, thank you! I haven't paid enough attention to that requirement! In this case I think you cannot avoid the copy...

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use `numpy.vectorize` this is one option:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> h_scalar = np.vectorize(lambda x: (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( -.50** x ** 2.00 ))
>>> l = np.array([-10.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0])
>>> h_scalar(l)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `np.vectorize` doesn't really give any performance benefit over a plain list comprehension - you'll still end up looping in Python rather than C

Answer (score 0):

To perform an operation on all items in a list (or another iterable object), creating a new list from the return values of the operation, you can do something like this:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [ 2 * x for x in l ]
>>> print l2
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

The Python language feature used on the second line here is called a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), and it's very well suited to the homework task you've been given.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Like this:

```
def h_scalar(sca):
    return [(1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-.50** x ** 2.00) for x in sca]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use power on a list instead of a list item.  I may have the exact function wrong here, but try something like this to take a list and return a list.

```
def h_scalar(x):
    return [(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-.50 ** i ** 2.0) for i in x]
```

I'm not sure you have the right equation though, could you re-format it?

```
In [14]: h_scalar(l)                                              
Out[14]: 
[0.3989422804014327,                                              
 0.24197072451914337,                                             
 0.14676266317373993,                                             
 0.24197072451914337,                                             
 0.3989422804014327]
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know i was doing that. I can now receive output, but it's not matching my teachers. My output is now "[0.3989422804014327, 0.24197072451914337, 0.14676266317373993, 0.24197072451914337, 0.3989422804014327]" whereas my instructor's is "[1.4867195147342977e-06, 0.24197072451914337, 0.3989422804014327, 0.24197072451914337, 1.4867195147342977e-06]" Am i calculating something wrong still?

Comment: [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) like svk and Piotr pointed out is one way to go.  Like I said, you'll want to double check your equation, but I can't tell from your formatting what you're trying to get.

Comment: Does this look like your original equation: [link](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}^{x^{2}}})

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np
import math
from math import *

def h_scalar(x):
    return (1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-.50** x ** 2.00)

l = [-10.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0]

**h_scalar = np.vectorize(h_scalar)**  ## you are missing this line in your code

print h_scalar(l)